# static content served by an nginx web server running in a container continutes to be available after the container is shut down

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-container

I am trying to expose some static html content via an **nginx** instance running in a container.

I start running the container on my local machine, a Mac running Mojave, using the command

```
docker run --name my-nginx --rm -v /mycontent:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -p 8080:80 nginx
```

where `mycontent` is the folder containing my static content.

In my browser I type `localhost:8080` and press enter and the content appears.

Now I stop the container and try again to load my content from the browser typing again `localhost:8080` and the content continues to appear, even if the nginx web server is no longer running since the container is down.

Why this behavior? Shouldn't the content not be served anymore since the web server was shut down?

Comment: first thing verify is docker really stop using `docker ps` , or it seems like the host system responding. try with `docker run --name my-nginx --rm -v /mycontent:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -p 8081:80 nginx` and verify with `localhost:8081` if same behaviour then something wrong with container.

Comment: This could very well be caching in your browser. If the nginx container is serving its content with relevant cache headers, the browser will not reach out to the nginx instance as long as the data is cached and valid. Open developer tools in your browser and inspect the response headers, check for cache. You can also open an incognito window once the container is down, and see that it fails to fetch the data (no cache should be used).